# Assuming $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, prove that $|f|$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question from a textbook:

Assuming $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, prove that $|f|$ is continuous

But I don't think this is true. $f(x) = x$ is continuous, but $f(x) = |x|$ is not uniformly continuous. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: The function $f(x) = |x|$ is uniformly continuous, and certainly continuous.  Are you perhaps confusing the definitions of "continuity" and "differentiability?"

Comment: What makes you think $f(x) = |x|$ is not uniformly continuous? (Also, I don't see where uniformity came from -- it's not in the textbook question.)

Comment: That's why it's proving that it's continuous, not uniformly continuous. Also, are you sure that's not uniformly continuous?

Comment: What is continuity of a function with no point specified, if it is not uniform continuity? Also @Shankman, yes that seems to be exactly what I had done.

Comment: @user7530 See above

Comment: A function is said to be continuous iff it is continuous in every point of its domain. Uniform continuity is a stronger property: there $\delta$ is required not to depend on $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the so-called reverse triangle inequality:
$$\left| |f(x)|-|f(a)| \right| \leq |f(x)-f(a)|.$$
Continuity of $f(x)$ means you can make $|f(x)-f(a)|$ small when $|x-a|$ is small, which means with the above you can make ...

Comment: I can't get this one, any more help?

Comment: Whats specifically don't you understand about the hint?

Comment: Oh I see now, so that means continuity of |f(x)| means that you cant make ||f(x) = |f(a)|| small by making |x-a| small, which we can see is already smaller or equal to f(x) case, hence with assumed continuity of f(x), |f(x) | is continuous. Is that right?

Comment: I think you understand, except you meant to say "can" instead of "cant". But yes. Make sure to understand the reverse triangle inequality and make sure to explain it in terms of epsilons and deltas.

Answer (score 0):

To say that a function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous means that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the following statement is true:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that the following is statement is true: if $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x - c| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.

So you are given that $f$ is continuous.  State what it means for the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = |f(x)|$ to be continuous; you should be able to prove this statement using  the fact that $$||s| - |t|| \leq |s - t|$$ for any real numbers $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

First, the absolute value function, let's denote it $h(x)=|x|$, is indeed uniformly continuous because it is Lipschitz (with $K=1$). Furthermore, the function $|f(x)|$ is the composition $h\circ f$ and the composition of two continuous functions is also continuous.